# LVM on separate disks?

Tags: boot, 18.04, partitioning, encryption, lvm

I have two physical disks. I want one to store my /home directory, and the other for root and system. Right now, I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 with encrypted LVM on disk 1. Now I want to prepare disk 2 for my /home directory.

Can I:

- encrypt disk 2 so that it uses the same password (only enter password once)
- make it so that disk 2 only stores /home files
- if I ever decide to format disk 1 will I be able to use disk 2?

Edit: Actually, turns out all this can be achieved by encrypting disk 2 separately, but then using keyfile rather than passphrase to decrypt it. So, PC boots from disk 1 asking for passphrase for disk 1, then it uses keyfile to decrypt disk 2. Since keyfile is stored on encrypted disk 1, it is safe.

Comment: You should have done all that during the installation. Now it'll be very hard and time consuming - creating a new `/home` and moving the old to the new - and encryption complicates things by a lot. Good luck.

Comment: The purpose of LVM is to provide an abstraction layer between the hardware and the filesystem, precisely so you *don't* assign a specific disk to a specific purpose. Your merge all the disks into one seamless storage pool, and use what you need from that pool for any purpose. One Logical Volume comprised of (one or) several disks.